# Url Routing Help Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have three url types. These:

first: http://localhost/
second: http://localhost/X/
third: http://localhost/X/Y/

Examples Url:

http://localhost/test/
http://localhost/test/details/

*first:*

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id =  UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

*second:*

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Module",
            "{module_name}/{controller}/{action}", 
            new
            {
                controller = "Module",
                action = "Index",
                module_name = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );

public class ModuleController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Module/

    public ActionResult Index(string modul_name)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

*third:*

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "ModuleDetails",
      "{module_name}/{details_param}/{controller}/{action}", 
      new
      {
          controller = "ModuleDetails",
          action = "Index",
          module_name = UrlParameter.Optional,
          details_param = UrlParameter.Optional
      }
);

public class ModuleDetailsController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /ModuleDetails/

    public ActionResult Index(string modul_name, string details_param)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

in this instance;

http://localhost/X/
 
*response:* "Home", "Index"

but;

http://localhost/X/
 
*response:* Application in the server error. Resource Not Found.

http://localhost/X/Y/
 
*response:* Application in the server error. Resource Not Found.

How can I do?
Thanks, best regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://localhost/X/
response: Application in the server error. Resource Not Found.

This happens because each of your routes specifies at least 2 mandatory parameters.

Try to add this one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}", 
            new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index"
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

that's right friends..

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Module",
            "{modul_name}",
            new { controller = "Modul", action = "Index", modul_name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Page",
            "{modul_name}/{page_name}",
            new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", modul_name = UrlParameter.Optional, page_name = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```